# datatables dropdown combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Im using Datatables from https://datatables.net.
One of the columns on the datatable has a dropdown combobox as cell data. 
When I push a button, I need to get the selected value of the combobox inside the selected row.

```
$.each($("#prize_selector tr.selected"), function () {
var row = prizes_table.row(this).data();
row[3].$('select').options[row[3].$('select').selectedIndex].id; 
[...]
});
```

but no success. How can I access the DOM select inside the cell, without traversing all the input selects on the table? (there are a lot).

**edit** the console throws row[3].$ is not a function

Comment: Please work up a JSFiddle (or similar) illustrating your use case.

Comment: I came to add the fiddle, but the Gyrocode.com's solution is just what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using Select extension to select rows.

Below is a correct way to access `select` element for each selected row:

```
table.rows({ selected: true }).every(function(){
   var $select = table.$('select', this.node());
   var $option = table.$('select option:selected', this.node());

   console.log($select.val(), $option);
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/z26e7w8m/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: thats exactly what I needed, didn't know we could filter by option:selected. Thank you!